# How to suppress source type in apacite (APA) reference list without removing the type-field entry

Tags: apa-style

I am using apacite for APA references in my thesis. It works beautifully with the exception that is displays the source type brackets in the reference list, which I don't want (see below). 
[image]
Leaving the `type` field blank is not an option because I manage my bibliography in EndNote and then export it, which automatically fills this field in.

Below is a minimum working example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{sources.bib}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}

\end{document}
```

My `.bib` file is rather inconspicuous, but I am including it for completeness.

```
@article{mandelbrot1963variation,
author = {Mandelbrot, Benoît},
title = {The variation of certain speculative prices},
journal = {The Journal of Business},
volume = {36},
number = {4},
pages = {394-419},
year = {1963},
type = {Journal Article}
}
```

Suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your example is not a working example: the bib is missing.

Comment: The command is `\nocite{*}`; what you've written is basically being treated as `\nocite{*}{}`, where the empty braces just add a space to an empty line.

Comment: The type is as you see it already in the bbl `...{\BBCQ}\ [Journal Article]`, so you can get rid of it only by either changing the bst-file, or by manipulating the bib (you could do it with biber + sourcemap). With biblatex-apa it would be easy to get rid of it.

Comment: Doesn't my answer solve your problem?

Comment: @karlkoeller, thank you for your answer. I was hoping there would be a way to do this without having to modify the .bst file and using apacite because I believe it conforms more exactly to APA style than BibLaTeX.

Comment: I'm sorry, there's no other way. In any case, that answers your question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## OPTION #1: using a modified `.bst` file

First of all, from the command line, run

> kpsewhich apacite.bst

to know where the file `apacite.bst` is. Its path should be `TEXMF/bibtex/bst/apacite/`.

Now copy `apacite.bst` in the directory where your `.tex` file is, and rename it to `myapacite.bst`.

Then open `myapacite.bst` in your editor, search for the lines

```
FUNCTION {format.atitle.type.check}
{ format.aetitle.check
  format.atype.check   connect.with.space.check
  title format.atitle.connect
}
```

and replace them with

```
FUNCTION {format.atitle.type.check}
{ format.aetitle.check
  title format.atitle.connect
}
```

Then search for the lines

```
FUNCTION {format.atitle.type.trans.check}
{ format.aetitle.check
  format.atype.check   connect.with.space.check
  format.atrans.check  connect.with.space.check
  title format.atitle.connect
}
```

and replace them with

```
FUNCTION {format.atitle.type.trans.check}
{ format.aetitle.check
  format.atrans.check  connect.with.space.check
  title format.atitle.connect
}
```

Save the file.

Now in your document, replace

```
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
```

with

```
\bibliographystyle{myapacite}
```

and you're done.

MWE

```
\begin{filecontents*}{sources.bib}
@article{mandelbrot1963variation,
author = {Mandelbrot, Benoît},
title = {The variation of certain speculative prices},
journal = {The Journal of Business},
volume = {36},
number = {4},
pages = {394-419},
year = {1963},
type = {Journal Article}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{sources}
\bibliographystyle{myapacite}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

---

Note that you have

```
\bibliography{sources.bib}
```

in your MWE, but it should be

```
\bibliography{sources}
```

unless your `.bib` file is named `sources.bib.bib`....

---

## OPTION #2: using `biblatex-apa`

Using `biblatex` with the `apa` style, the `type` field isn't printed by default.

Here's your MWE modified for using `biblatex`:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{sources.bib}
@article{mandelbrot1963variation,
author = {Mandelbrot, Benoît},
title = {The variation of certain speculative prices},
journal = {The Journal of Business},
volume = {36},
number = {4},
pages = {394-419},
year = {1963},
type = {Journal Article}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[%
    style=apa,
    natbib=true,
    firstinits=true,
    uniquename=init,
    backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}

\addbibresource{sources.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Can you tell how to change the year from (2015) to just 2015? analogously, I tried searching the bst file for parentheses and similar, but found nothing!